# Sonata Admin Bundle - adding simple access control

Tags: .htaccess, symfony, sonata-admin, sonata-user-bundle

I'm quite new to Sonata Admin Bundle and I'm trying to make the User bundle work, however what I really need is just to limit acces to the admin area to a single administrator so it may be a bit of an overhead. Is it feasibile with all the symfony dynamic routing to secure the access with something as simple as an .htaccess rule or sth similar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd recommend restricting access to `/admin` path to a role (e.g. `ROLE_ADMIN`) and assigning the role only to the user, that should have said access:

```
# app/config/security.yml
security:
    # ...
    access_control:
        # require ROLE_ADMIN for /admin*
        - { path: ^/admin, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
```

For more info on Access Controll see [documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html#denying-access-roles-and-other-authorization).

Comment: Thanks! I must have missed that part of documentation [blush]. I'll check this out and see if it answers my question, i.e. is easier to setup than Sonata User Bundle and accept the answer then.

Comment: You're welcome. If you are satified with the answer, please accept it as correct. It helps others to find correct answers and helps us to identify questions, that still need attention.